# Aggregating over timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the maximum bid-ask spread per second. Suppose I have this file of quotes:

```
In [1]: !head quotes.txt
exchtime|bid|ask
1389178814.587758|520.0000|541.0000
1389178830.462050|540.4300|540.8700
1389178830.462050|540.4300|540.8700
1389178830.468602|540.4300|540.8600
1389178830.468602|540.4300|540.8600
1389178847.67500|540.4300|540.8500
1389178847.67500|540.4300|540.8500
1389178847.73541|540.4300|540.8400
1389178847.73541|540.4300|540.8400
```

The timestamps are simply seconds since epoch in UTC. With some tricks on the first column, I can read the file like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

def convert(x): return np.datetime64(datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x)).isoformat())

df = pd.read_csv('quotes.txt', sep='|', parse_dates=True, converters={0:convert})
```

And this produces what I want:

```
In [10]: df.head()
Out[10]:
                    exchtime     bid     ask
0 2014-01-08 11:00:14.587758  520.00  541.00
1 2014-01-08 11:00:30.462050  540.43  540.87
2 2014-01-08 11:00:30.462050  540.43  540.87
3 2014-01-08 11:00:30.468602  540.43  540.86
4 2014-01-08 11:00:30.468602  540.43  540.86
```

I get stumped on the aggregation. In q/kdb+, I would simply do:

```
select spread:max ask-bid by exchtime.second from df
```

What I came-up with in Pandas is

```
df['spread'] = df.ask - df.bid
df['exchtime_sec'] = [e.replace(microsecond=0) for e in df.exchtime]
df.groupby('exchtime_sec')['spread'].agg(np.max)
```

This appears to work, but the `exchtime_sec` line takes about three orders of magnitude longer than expected to run! Is there a faster (and more concise) way to express this aggregation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read in like this, w/o converting the times with a converter

```
In [11]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='|')
```

This is much faster

```
In [12]: df['exchtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['exchtime'],unit='s')

In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
                    exchtime     bid     ask
0 2014-01-08 11:00:14.587758  520.00  541.00
1 2014-01-08 11:00:30.462050  540.43  540.87
2 2014-01-08 11:00:30.462050  540.43  540.87
3 2014-01-08 11:00:30.468602  540.43  540.86
4 2014-01-08 11:00:30.468602  540.43  540.86
5 2014-01-08 11:00:47.675000  540.43  540.85
6 2014-01-08 11:00:47.675000  540.43  540.85
7 2014-01-08 11:00:47.735410  540.43  540.84
8 2014-01-08 11:00:47.735410  540.43  540.84

[9 rows x 3 columns]
```

Create the spread column

```
In [15]: df['spread'] = df.ask-df.bid
```

Set the index to the exchtime, resample at 1second interval and take the max
for the aggregator

```
In [16]: df.set_index('exchtime').resample('1s',how=np.max)
Out[16]: 
                        bid     ask  spread
exchtime                                   
2014-01-08 11:00:14  520.00  541.00   21.00
2014-01-08 11:00:15     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:16     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:17     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:18     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:19     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:20     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:21     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:22     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:23     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:24     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:25     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:26     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:27     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:28     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:29     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:30  540.43  540.87    0.44
2014-01-08 11:00:31     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:32     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:33     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:34     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:35     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:36     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:37     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:38     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:39     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:40     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:41     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:42     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:43     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:44     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:45     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:46     NaN     NaN     NaN
2014-01-08 11:00:47  540.43  540.85    0.42

[34 rows x 3 columns]
```

Performance Comparison

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,2),index=date_range('20130101',periods=100000,freq='50U'))

In [7]: def f1(df):
   ...:     df = df.copy()
   ...:     df['seconds'] = [ e.replace(microsecond=0) for e in df.index ]
   ...:     df.groupby('seconds')[0].agg(np.max)
   ...:     

In [11]: def f2(df):
   ....:     df = df.copy()
   ....:     df.resample('1s',how=np.max)
   ....:     

In [8]: %timeit f1(df)
1 loops, best of 3: 692 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit f2(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
```

Here is another way to do this, which for a lower frequency is faster. (high/low are equivalent of max/min, where open is first, close is last).

```
In [9]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000,2),index=date_range('20130101',periods=100000,freq='50L'))

In [10]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1s'))[0].ohlc()
Out[10]: 
In [11]: %timeit df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1s'))[0].ohlc()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm still having trouble with the performance though. If I use your 100000 random samples with 50U frequency, I timeit at 3.62 ms, in line with what you have. But if I go with 50L frequency and the same number of samples, then I timeit at 612 ms! The higher frequency is far more in line with my tick samples, so my real-world performance is still exasperating. Any thoughts on higher frequencies? My assumption is that pandas is tripping-up on each new index value.

Comment: so the 2 distributions are quite different, with many more values per 1s with U vs L (of course that's how it was constructed). If you use a cythonized function (e.g. np.mean/np.sum/np.prod/np.var/np.median), then you will get a similar performance. max/min are not cythonized so it falls back to a slower method (needs an enhancement to fix this)...i'll open an issue. You can also use first/last in a slightly different way. You might also try ohlc which should work as well. I'll edit the question.

Comment: issue about perf or max/min (but you should use OHLC in any event) https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5927. My prior comments are off (np.max/min) ARE cythonized, but for some reason the slower path is taken.